# Trench all the way around the basement?

Tags: basement, sump-pump

I have water coming up between the floor and foundation in my basement. In heavy rains it starts in the northwest corner. If the rain continues it will start in the northeast corner. If it's really bad I'll get it in the southwest corner and, eventually, the southeast corner. The last two are less likely to occur.

Now, all the sump pump installation companies want to come in and trench all the way around the foundation of my basement to install drain pipe to run into one pit. The question asked of me is, wouldn't a sump in one corner of the basement relieve the pressure enough to drain it all without having to run drains all the way around?

Comment: What material is the basement floor made of?  Does your property slope downward significantly away from the house? If you are trenching I can think of better things to trench...

Comment: @Harper The floor is concrete. The property slopes toward the house (see my other question here). Trenching and install drain pipe is the norm and not unusual at all.

Comment: Is it a finished basement?  If so, the trenching will destroy the finishing work, so I would start with just sump pumps in the NW and NE corners and see how effective they are.  Water will migrate some, but one pump isn't likely to drain the entire foundation.  Two probably won't drain the far end of the house (maybe eventually, but they won't take it away fast enough during a heavy rain).

Comment: @fixer1234 I've had a house with one pump and that works just fine. My neighbors have one pump.

Comment: Sometimes it does and sometimes water doesn't migrate fast enough to stay ahead of heavy rain.  That's why I suggested starting with just pumps in the worst areas before trenching.  You want two pumps, anyway, because a hole in the floor is a 2-way path and if one pump fails, you've created a water collection system using your basement as a storage device.  The second pump is a backup.  Consider also using some type of backup power for at least one pump (battery or dual power or a backup generator).  A storm is the most likely time to lose power, and the sump pit becomes a path in.